# GameObject doesn't return the correct boolean value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a class in c# named `Tile`, with an attribute boolean and when I try to access it via the method `getIsWall()` I get always `True`. Attached the code.

Before to start I generate a 100x100 grid of gameObject using the method `createTile()`, for "Walls" I set `isWall` to `true` and for "free" tiles I set `isWall` to `false`. (see the method)

Then in `generateAisle` method I want to create an aisle going North (forced direction = 1 for debug case) and I check if 3 tiles are walls using the method `checkIfWall()`. When I do it I get back ALWAYS `TRUE`, but I know that sometime a tile is `FALSE` (checking while the game is running).

Someone can help me? Thanks!

```
public void generateAisle(int x, int z, int lengthAisle){
    bool free = false;
    bool free2 = false;
    bool free3 = false;
    int direction = 1;//Random.Range (1, 4);
        if (direction == 1) {//north
            int tempZ = z+1;
            for (int i=0; i<lengthAisle; i++) {
                free = checkIfWall (x, tempZ+i);
                free2 = checkIfWall ((x-1), tempZ+i);
                free3 = checkIfWall ((x+1), tempZ+i);
                if(!free || !free2 || !free3){
                    free = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(free){
                for (int i=0; i<lengthAisle; i++) {
                    /*Destroy(GameObject.Find("Tile"+x+"."+(tempZ+i)));
                    createTile(x,z+i,"Free");*/
                }
            }
        } else if (direction == 2) {//south
            int tempZ = z-1;
            for (int i=0; i<lengthAisle; i++) {
                free = checkIfWall (x+i, tempZ);
                free2 = checkIfWall (x-1+i, tempZ);
                free3 = checkIfWall (x+1+i, tempZ);
                if(!free || !free2 || !free3){
                    free = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(free){
                for (int i=0; i<lengthAisle; i++) {
                    Destroy(GameObject.Find("Tile"+x+"."+(tempZ+i)));
                    createTile(x,z+i,"Free");
                }
            }
        } else if (direction == 3) {//east
            for (int i=0; i<lengthAisle; i++) {
                free = checkIfWall (x, z + i);
            }
        } else if (direction == 4) {//west
            for (int i=0; i<lengthAisle; i++) {
                free = checkIfWall (x, (z - i));
            }
        }
}
private bool checkIfWall(int x, int z){
    Debug.Log (GameObject.Find ("Tile" + x + "." + z).GetComponent<Tile> ().getIsWall());
    if (GameObject.Find ("Tile" + x + "." + z) != null) {
        Debug.Log ("Tile" + x + "." + z + " = " + GameObject.Find ("Tile" + x + "." + z).GetComponent<Tile> ().getIsWall());
        if (GameObject.Find ("Tile" + x + "." + z).GetComponent<Tile> ().getIsWall()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void createTile(int x, int z, string kind="Wall"){
    GameObject newTile = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(kind, typeof(GameObject)));
    newTile.name = "Tile"+x+"."+z;
    newTile.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>().setPosition(x,z);
    if (kind == "Wall") {
        newTile.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, 1, z);
        newTile.GetComponent<Tile>().setWall(true);
    }else{
        newTile.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, 0, z);
        newTile.GetComponent<Tile>().setWall(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the getIsWall function. Note that frequently performing Find and frequently appending strings with + is highly inefficient. You should "find" the object once and store it in a local variable rather than constructing the string and finding it over and over again. Also you can just do "return ... getIsWall()" rather than if/else that return true/false depending on whether getIsWall return true/false.

Comment: You are right about hte method checkIfWall, isnt a good solution, I will try to simplify. Then I will follow your suggestion, I will save the reference to the gameobject in an array when is created!

Answer (score 0):

After suggestion of @LearnCocos2D I removed all the "GameObject.Find()" and simply returned the tile created in createTile() and stored the reference in an array. Then when needed I check if the stored GameObject is a wall.